# Play is downloading a file instead of streaming it

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-stream

I'm trying to create an API that takes a file from AWS S3 and sends it to a front end where it can be played. But when I test it in a browser, it just downloads the file. I need the file to be played.

My action:

```
def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
  val songname: String = "song.mp3"
  val objStream = s3.client.getObject("music", songname).getObjectContent

  val dataContent: Source[ByteString, _] = StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() => objStream)

  Ok.chunked(dataContent).withHeaders(ACCEPT_RANGES -> "bytes", CONTENT_TYPE -> "Content-Type: audio/mp3")
}
```

Also, it ignores my `content_type` header:

```
[warn] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Explicitly set HTTP header 'Content-Type: Content-Type: audio/mp3' is ignored, illegal RawHeader
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`as`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/mvc/Result.html#as(contentType:String):play.api.mvc.Result) instead of `withHeaders`:

```
def index() = Action { implicit request =>
  val songname = "song.mp3"
  val objStream = s3.client.getObject("music", songname).getObjectContent

  val dataContent: Source[ByteString, _] =
    StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() => objStream)

  Ok.chunked(dataContent).as("audio/mp3")
                       // ^
}
```